# R ggplot2 change geom_bar to a single color

Tags: r, ggplot2

Based on the code and data below, how can I change the bar colors to a single color `#0277BD`?

I tried `scale_fill_manual(values=c("#0277BD"))`, but it doesn't work.

```
Error in `f()`:
! Insufficient values in manual scale. 24 needed but only 1 provided.
```

I also tried `scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues")`, but this doesn't work either.

```
Warning message:
In RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n, pal) :
  n too large, allowed maximum for palette Blues is 9
Returning the palette you asked for with that many colors
```

Data:

```
df = structure(list(CITYNAME = c("a", "b", "c", 
    "d", "e", "f", "g", 
    "h", "i", "j", "k", 
    "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", 
    "r", "s", "t", "u", 
    "w", "x", "y", "z"), AvgTMin = c(20.28, 
20.38, 20.08, 20.35, 20.38, 20.76, 21, 21.21, 20.45, 20.21, 21.18, 
20.29, 20.61, 20.44, 20.95, 19.75, 20.58, 20.32, 21.05, 20.28, 
20.09, 20.15, 20.73, 20.12)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Code:

```
# Plot in Fahrenheit

    df %>% mutate(AvgTMin = AvgTMin * (1.8) + 32) %>% # Convert from C to F
          ggplot(aes(x = reorder(CITYNAME,AvgTMin), y = AvgTMin, fill = CITYNAME)) +
          geom_bar(stat="identity") +
          coord_cartesian(ylim = c(60,70.3)) +
          theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 14)) +
          geom_text(aes(label=sprintf("%0.2f", AvgTMin)), vjust=-0.2, size = 4) +
          labs(x = NULL, y = "Avg. Min. Temperature \u00B0F") + 
          theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),  legend.position = 'none') +
          ggtitle("1980-2021 Temperature Trend By City")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the single color in the `geom_bar` call:

```
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill = "0277BD") +
```

In your code you can also delete the `fill` aesthetic in the `ggplot` call unless you need it for other layers.

Answer (score 1):

Another option if wanted to leave the `fill` parameter alone, then you could still use `scale_fill_manual`, but you would need to replicate color for all of the unique values.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(AvgTMin = AvgTMin * (1.8) + 32) %>% # Convert from C to F
  ggplot(aes(
    x = reorder(CITYNAME, AvgTMin),
    y = AvgTMin,
    fill = CITYNAME
  )) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(60, 70.3)) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 14)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = sprintf("%0.2f", AvgTMin)), vjust = -0.2, size = 4) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Avg. Min. Temperature \u00B0F") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        legend.position = 'none') +
  ggtitle("1980-2021 Temperature Trend By City") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rep_len("#0277BD", length(unique(df$CITYNAME))))
```

**Output**

[image]